# Smallest possible value of $k$ such that the roots of $x^2-127x+k=0$ are positive integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, triangles, problem-solving, discriminant

In a triangle, two sides have equal lengths both shorter than the third side. The length of the three sides are all integers and all satisfy the equation  $x^2-127x+k=0$, $k$ is a constant. Find the smallest possible value of $k$.

Discriminant $(Δ)$ of the quadratic equation: $Δ = b^2 - 4ac.$
In this case, $a = 1$, $b = -127$, and $c = k$, so
$Δ = (-127)^2 - 4(1)(k) = 16129 - 4k.$

$Δ > 0 \implies
16129 - 4k > 0.$

Solving for $k$:
$4k < 16129 \implies
k < 4032.25.$

Since $k$ must be an integer, which is $4031$.

Where did I get wrong?

Comment: You found a necessary condition, which is that $k \le 4032$, but all such $k$ don't satisfy that the solutions $x$ of the quadratic equation are integers. Also you are looking for the smallest $k$, not the largest $k$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note that, as indicated in [Gribouillis's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4752095/smallest-possible-value-of-k#comment10085038_4752095) above, you also need to ensure the $2$ quadratic root values are distinct, positive integers (i.e., with a necessary condition being that $\Delta$ is a perfect square), and that the resulting side lengths satisfy the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Comment: hi @Gribouillis, thanks for reply. Can you elaborate more on this? How should I proceed from here to look for smallest k?

Comment: $\Delta$ is the square of an odd integer, write $\Delta = (2 d + 1)^2$. We can suppose that $d\ge 0$. Write the lengths of the sides of the triangle in terms of $d$, then use the triangle inequality. This leaves you only a small set of possible values of $d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the reason why your approach isn't enough from the comments.  Below is an approach that will find the smallest $k$.

Let $a$ be the length of the short sides and $a+x$ be the length of the longer one.  Then $0<x<a$ for a non-degenerate triangle.

From Vieta's relations, we have $2a+x=127$, and $k=a(a+x)=\frac14(127^2-x^2)$. Thus $k$ will be minimised when we  maximise $x$. Putting $x=a-1$, we get $3a-1=127\implies a\not \in \mathbb Z$.  Next we have $x=a-2 \implies 3a-2=127$ giving $(a, b) = (43, 84)$ and $k_{min}=3612$.

Comment: what does the term 1/4 (127^2 - x^2) means ( or comes from)?

Comment: @tjunkitmin Substitute for $a$ using $2a+x=127$.